# How to Block images (img tags) from an iFrame?

Tags: java, iframe, tags, image

Im searching for ideas to solve the following problem:

I'm loading an URL (any for that matter) into an iFrame, and then block (server side) all image tags, o object tags before sending the page to the client.

--
What I was thinking to do is: fetching the URL, and then manipulating the fetched content using a Java library (any recomendation on that matter?). And after that, send the modify content to que client.

Would that be the best approach to solve this problem? suggestions are wellcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)
It's java based and pretty simple to use.  You can fetch all 'img' tags and replace if required.

jSoup is another option.  I prefer HTML Parser though.

--
Sid

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [nekoHtml](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/), which allow you to treat html like xml.